# ReactriveX: Catching exceptions on Observable<bool> as lambda expression

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've this observable:

```
public class NetworkToolEngine
{
    public NetworkToolEngine()
    {            
        this.connectionAvailable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Select(_ => true);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        NetWorkToolEngine networkToolEngine = new NetworkToolEngine();
        this.networkToolEngine.ConnectionAvailable
            .Do(_ => this.ConnectionAvailable())
            .Catch(ex =>    //<<<<<1>>>>>
            {
                this.ConnectionUnavailable();
                return Observable.Empty<bool>();
            });
    }
```

Currently; I'm getting this compilation error at `<<<<<1>>>>>`:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IObservable' because it is not a delegate type

Any ideas?

Comment: This code is clearly not your actual code - it doesn't have a hope of compiling. Could you please post valid code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because there are multiple overloads of catch and without you specifying type of `ex` - it chooses the wrong one. You need to do it like this:

```
.Catch((Exception ex) =>    //<<<<<1>>>>>
{
    this.ConnectionUnavailable();
    return Observable.Empty<bool>();
});
```